# Accessing the first image when the second image of a two image div is hover or clicked

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have a div containing two images which is wrapped with a hover event.  These images are left and right arrows.  When I hover on the right arrow, I need to change the opacity on the left arrow.  The html code is:

```
<div class="arrows">
   <img src="left-arrow.jpg"  id="left" />
   <img src="right-arrow.jpg" id="right" />
</div>
```

jquery code

```
$('.arrows img').hover(function() {
    var imgId = $(this).attr('id');
    if (imgId == "right") {
        // change opacity on left arrow
        $(this).parent().img.eq(0).css({"opacity" : .5});  // does not work
        $('arrows img.eq(0)').css({"opacity" : .5});       // does not work
    }
});
```

Any suggestion that I can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.arrows img').hover(function() {

    $(this).siblings().css({"opacity" : .5});

});
```

Edit:

If you are looking to gray out the left or right arrow based on first or last page do this:

On Hover:

```
  $('.arrows img').hover(function() {

    $(this).css({"opacity" : .5});

});
```

On Click:

```
  $('.arrows img').click(function() {

    $(this).css({"opacity" : .5});

});
```

Comment: No effect.  I also need to be able to click on the left and change the right arrow.  What I doing is implementing left and right arrows.  When I get to the limit of either side, that side gets grayed out.

Comment: @user50881: I'm not sure what you mean by no effect, the snippet i provided correctly reduces the opacity of the other image by 50%. That's what you asked for in the question.

Comment: If you want the behavior on click, then replace .hover with .click

Comment: If you are trying to gray out the arrow image when you have reached the extreme left or right position, then you need to do $(this).css({"opacity":.5}); instead of sibling.

Comment: It works.  I placed it in an incorrect location in my logic. Thank you

Comment: Just click the check sign below the UP Down arrows you see next to my answer on the top.